# Arguing with the Rishonim

Tags: torah-study, rishonim, machlokes

Is there an accepted understanding among Orthodox Jews that an Achron cannot argue with a Rishon (Torah scholars who lived between the years 1000 and 1500)? If so,what is this concept based on and what are the guidelines for this rule?

Comment: +1 I heard that the Ragechaver Gaon did argue with rishonim